# ActiveAdmin not sending password confirmation instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I recently installed ActiveAdmin and I am working on the User model. After I created the initial AdminUser I tried adding another AdminUser and its supposed to send an email to set up the password but it fails to send the email.

I have this code in my config/development folder

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

and this in my AdminUser model

```
after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }
def password_required?
 new_record? ? false : super
end
```

Not sure why its not sending the email for me to change my password.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting problem because you didn't configure any server to go out an emails.
You are on right path. just add following things.

Please add following line to app/Gemfile and run bundle install.

```
gem "letter_opener"
```

and then add following line to config/enviornments/development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
```

Above code will help you to see the result in the browser itself, doesn't actually sends the email.

To send an actual email you need to change following line and need to add smtp code.(smtp server)

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Then add following lines below above line:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'gmail',
    :user_name            => 'gmail username',
    :password             => 'gmail password',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```